# DOMDocument::save[domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, xml, apache, curl

I have a code which would save an XML file to my directory. It is actually works like a charm in my localhost & in my shared host BUT its not working in my Linux VPS.

I always got this error:

Warning: DOMDocument::save(/home/admin/xxxxxx) [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/admin/xxxxx on line 240

What can I do now? I have chmod 777 the directory and still not working...

Comment: change the permission of the file? Contact your provider?

Comment: I have changed the permission of the file to 777, what else should I do?

Comment: I have a VPS, its unmanaged, so I guess he cannot do anything for me. I think I could also get rid of this problem on my own, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have the right to write something in this **folder**, even if the **file** is read/writable. Try

```
cd /said/folder
chmod a+w .
```

If this works, try to narrow down the rw rights by *removing* the write bit for *everyone*:

```
chmod a-w .
```

And only granting it to the default web server *group* (see your GNU/Linux distribution manual) eg:

```
chown .www-data .
```