# I can write to xml but i can't edit it in php

Tags: php, xml

Really frustrated. I am using my university's network, I have successfully created and wrote to an xml file using php. But when I try to edit the file, change the value of a node, I was unsuccessful, and got a Permission denied error.

```
$xmlfile = '../../data/goods.xml';
$doc = new DomDocument();

// some more code ...

$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->save($xmlfile);
```

Therefore my goods.xml is created

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id>0</id>
    <itemprice>9.99</itemprice>
    <itemqty>10</itemqty>
    <qtyonhold>0</qtyonhold>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <itemprice>19.99</itemprice>
    <itemqty>20</itemqty>
    <qtyonhold>0</qtyonhold>
  </item>
```

Now I need to increase the quantity on hold, say + 1

```
// in my php file 
$itemid = 1;
function putItemOnHold($itemid, $itemprice) {
    $xmlfile = "../../data/goods.xml";
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE; 

    $doc->load($xmlfile);

    // look for the item node
    $item = $doc->getElementsByTagName("item")->item(0);

    // loop through all item nodes
    foreach($item as $node) {
      $availableId = $node->getElementsByTagName("id")->item(0)->nodeValue;

      // look for that item
      if ($itemid == $availableId) {
        // get the item quantity& quantity on hold node
        // update the quantity & quantity on hold
        $availableQty= $node->getElementsByTagName("itemqty")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $node->getElementsByTagName("itemqty")->item(0)->nodeValue = $availableQty - 1;
        $availableQtyOnHold= $node->getElementsByTagName("qtyonhold")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $node->getElementsByTagName("qtyonhold")->item(0)->nodeValue = $availableQtyOnHold - 1;

        break;
      }
    }
    // save the updated xml file
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    // $doc->save($xmlfile); // Tried that but --- failed to open stream: Permission denied in (../../goods.xml)
    // $doc->save($xmlfile); // i used did this in my register php file, worked, but not in this file
    $doc->saveXML();
  }
```

Any hero here able to spot the problem? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Did you check the file write permissions? Permission Denied usually has to do with file access permissions. And it has to be writable by the server user (eg, apache (Unix) or www-user (Windows) for Apache)

Comment: @abhikarma1493 Yes the server should be fine because I was able to create and write on that xml file, but now I can't edit it.

Comment: You should use ls -ltZ on your server and check if your file has SELinux restrictions. Usually, I have to change my writable files like this:  

`chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t FILENAME`  

These are extra restrictions added to latest Linux servers.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50641

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18785880/3159895